# Hibernate Search Query for timestamp returns empty list

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search, hibernate-query

I am working on a Spring Boot Project with Hibernate and I'm trying to map timestamps out of an SQL-Database. Other queries against strings or numbers work fine, so the problem should not be the project structure itself.

Snippet of my User.java class:

```
@Indexed
@Entity

public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  @Field
  @Basic
  private java.sql.Timestamp datum;

  public java.sql.Timestamp getDatum() {
    return datum;
  }
}
```

Snippet of my search service:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
    org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.
    getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

QueryBuilder queryBuilder =
    fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(User.class).get();

org.apache.lucene.search.Query query =
        queryBuilder.range().onField("datum")
          .below(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("1980-02-01 11:02:20.000")).createQuery();

org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery jpaQuery =
    fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, User.class);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<User> results = (List<User>) jpaQuery.getResultList();

return results;
```

Comment: Do you have an example of a database record? My guess is that your timestamp format is not correct.

Comment: @cmoetzing  
timestamp as set in db: 
UPDATE `user` SET `datum` = '1970-02-02 00:00:00' WHERE `user`.`id` = 1;

timestamp as shown when I show all entries with hibernate search:
[{"id":1,"datum":"1970-02-01T23:00:00.000+0000",

Comment: Have you tried to simplify your problem? Maybe do a simple query that exactly looks for your date. 

`getCurrentHibernateSession().createCriteria(User.class).add(Restrictions.eq("datum", Timestamp.valueOf("1970-02-02 00:00:00")));`

I never worked with lucene queries thus I have no idea if you _range()_ and _below()_ is correct.

Comment: If you just added this `@Field` annotation on the `datum` property, check that you [reindexed your database](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex) before you try new queries. If it still doesn't work, it might be a bug. You could try to build a reproducer using the [Hibernate Search test case templates](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search), and if you manage to reproduce the problem, you can report a bug on [JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HSEARCH).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use SpringJPA no?

So it would then just be an interface

```
@Repository
public interface YourModelRepository extends JpaRepository<YourModel, Integer>{
        List<YourModel> findByDatumGreaterThan(LocalDatetime datum);
}
```

Let JPA's interface take care of it.

Here's the [spring jpa reference sheet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/).

Comment: Cheers. Glad I could help. :)